# Obtaining Inverse configuration space metric $M^{AB}$ in canonical gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-gravity

I am considering phase space of configuration variables in general scalar tensor theory $(q^A=(h_{ab},\phi))$,  characterised by the metric:

$ M_{AB}=\frac{\sqrt{h}}{N}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{U(\phi)}{2}G^{abcd}&-U'(\phi)h^{ab}\\-U'(\phi)h^{cd}&G(\phi)\end{pmatrix};
 $

prime denotes derivative w.r.t scalar field $\phi$) and $h$ is standard spatial metric  in ADM decomposition.

From relation:

$M_{AC}M^{CB}=\delta_A^B,\;\; \delta_A^B=diag(\delta_{ab}^{cd},1)$
where $\delta_{ab}^{cd}=G_{abkl}G^{klcd}=\delta_{(a}^c \delta^{d}_{b)}.$

Supermetric is defined by $ G^{abcd}=\frac{1}{2}(h^{ac}h^{db}+h^{ad}h^{cb}-2h^{ab}h^{cd})$, $G_{abcd}=h_{a(c}h_{d)b}-\frac{1}{2}h_{ab}h_{cd}).$

The inverse metric on the configurational space  is given by:

$ M^{AB}=\frac{N}{\sqrt{h}}\begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{U(\phi)}G_{abcd}+s(U'/U)^2h_{ab}h_{cd}&-s(U'/U)h_{ab}\\-s(U'/U)h_{cd}&s\end{pmatrix}$
with $s=\frac{U}{(GU+3(U')^2)}$

I have trouble with obtaining this inverted metric. While standard metric inverse satisfy $g g^{-1}=I$, applying similar procedure led me to set of 4 equations for 4 components, i.e $M^{AB}$'s. However, "brainless" computation didn't worked, since one deals with tensorial quantities such as $h$'s and supermetric $G^{abcd}$ or double delta symbol (in $(1,1)$-th component).   For example, using naive substitutions i have for $M^{22}$ component expression $\frac{G^{abcd}(U/2)}{G^{abcd}(U/2)-(U')^2h^{cd}h^{ab}}$ (correct one is $s$)

As a reference, im following section 6.2 (eqs. (6.11), (6.15)) of    https://inspirehep.net/literature/1784294
(in this ref., metric $h=\gamma$ and $U_1=U'$).

How to perform this inversion correctly in order to get $M^{AB}$?

Comment: I don't understand the upper left term, you cannot have a four index object in that slot. Can you clarify notation? And I assume for the bottom right entry you have an implicit identity matrix.

Comment: Metric on configurational space is defined such that it can reproduce Lagrangian density $L=(1/2)N^2D_tq^AM_{ab}D_tq^B-P("potential")$. Since ${q^A=(h_{ab}, \phi}) $,  $M_{11} $ acts  on $D_th_{ab}=2K_{ab} $and $D_th_{cd}=2K_{cd} $ and reproduces familiar expression $\sim G^{abcd} K_{ab} K_{cd} $ and same for other components (Bth component is asociated with $cd$ and Ath with $ab$) In definition for this inverse, second diagonal component is precisely $1$ (not the id. matrix)